# Azure Mobile Service Insert Error

Tags: azure, mobile, service

I have created an Azure Mobile Service (JavaScript Backend) and many times when I call the Insert from the client it errors out.

The mobile service is in the free mode.

Answer (score 0):

If you got this

"Could not insert an item because an item with that id already exists."

it means you are inserting in the same table an object with the same id, this way if you have Car and it has Id property that is the key, you are doing

- insert car with id 1
- insert car with id 1

and then you got the error!

you should do

- insert car with id 1
- insert car with id 2

Comment: Not really, actually the message is returned when we retry after failure.

Comment: what? if you have there 1 object with id=1 you cannot try to insert another object with id=1......

Comment: It seems you did not understand my comment. What I am saying is I inserted object with id=1, it failed and did not return success status code, then when I tried again, it says "... id already exists", which means even though object was saved inserted/correctly, it ended in error state.

Comment: When you insert the first item, are you sure it is empty?  can you share code in your initial post, please? Edit it.... and show ate least the model and the service used